# Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Tags: ffmpeg

When i tried to merge an avi file with a wav file it shows the error
"Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height".

I will inlude my code as well as my command line ouptput here.

Code:

ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SUNP0001.AVI"  -i "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\temp.wav"  -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental  "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new1.avi"

CommandLine Output

```
E:\vishnu>ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SUNP0001.AVI"  -i "C:\Users\admin\De
sktop\temp.wav"  -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental  "C:\Users\admin\Deskto
p\new1.avi"
ffmpeg version N-59036-g5d8e4f6 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 12 2013 22:01:01 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 58.100 / 52. 58.100
  libavcodec     55. 45.101 / 55. 45.101
  libavformat    55. 22.100 / 55. 22.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     3. 92.100 /  3. 92.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[avi @ 03715e40] non-interleaved AVI
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SUNP0001.AVI':
  Duration: 00:00:11.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16310 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc), 1280x720, 30.08
 tbr, 30.08 tbn, 30.08 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 11025 Hz, mono, s16,
176 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, wav, from 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\temp.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:14.68, bitrate: 384 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 24000 Hz, mono, s16,
384 kb/s
[aac @ 0371a720] Too many bits per frame requested
Output #0, avi, to 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new1.avi':
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 9
0k tbn, 30.08 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 11025 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> aac)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters
such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

E:\vishnu>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Your bitrate is too high for 11,025 Hz Mono audio. 128 kBit/s is just too much for the encoder.

You need to lower the bitrate by adding `-b:a 32k` or similar.

Comment: This didn't seem to be true for me.

Comment: @Ryan It probably depends on what version you used; some versions may not check as strictly or there is already a workaround for this issue. (It could for example simply cap the bitrate internally without complaining.)